# Print 2nd line in text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file that is returning the following text:

```
10.10.10.160:1111
10.10.10.170:2222
10.10.10.180:3333
```

```
grep -m 1 -o '.*' filename | cut -d ':' -f
```

I tried the above and I can get just 1 single line of output.

```
10.10.10.160
```

However when I tried with

```
grep -m 2 -o '.*' filename | cut -d ':' -f
```

```
10.10.10.160
10.10.10.170
```

I get the above.

If I want to get just the 2nd line

```
10.10.10.170
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
grep -m 2 -o '.*' filename | cut -d ':' -f 1 | tail -n 1
```

Results:

```
10.10.10.170
```

`tail -n 1` prints only the last line of the results of  `grep -m 2 -o '.*' filename | cut -d ':' -f 1`

The original text file is named filename.

Answer (score 26):

```
head -2 filename | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 1
```

Answer (score 19):

I'd suggest awk for this kind of task:

```
awk -F: 'NR==2 {print $1}' filename
```

Alternatively with sed:

```
sed -n '2s/:.*//p' filename
```

If the file is *large*, you may want to change those to

```
awk -F: 'NR==2 {print $1; exit}' filename
```

and

```
sed -n '2{s/:.*//p;q;}' filename
```

respectively, to avoid unnecessarily processing later lines.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -e '2!d' -e 's/:.*//' filename
```

or, in a bit more compact way:

```
sed '{2!d; s/:.*//; q;}' filename
```

- `2!d` tells `sed` to delete (`d`) all lines except (`!`) the second (`2`) line.
- `'s/:.*//'` tells `sed` to remove everything after `:` (including `:`).
- In the second case `q` is used to terminate the operation immediately after it's completed (useful for larger files - thanks @JoL for the suggestion).

Comment: *possibly* easier to read: `sed -n 2p`

Comment: Definitely easier. That's what steeldriver uses in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it purely with the shell (assuming bash), without the use of any other utilities:

```bash
{
    read
    IFS=: read ip port
    echo $ip
} < input.txt
```

Starting at the end, the `<` redirects `input.txt` to the `{ }` command group.  The first `read` then reads 1 line and discards it.  The second `read` reads the next line, and `IFS` separates it by colon `:`.  The second `read` populates the `ip` and `port` variables with the 1st and 2nd elements of the second line.  The `$ip` variable is the output by `echo`.